# color by clusters and sampled in Seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have a Seurat object

I want to have both cluster numbers and coloured cells by sample names like this figure (from a Nature paper)

[image]

I have tried `group.by` argument in Seurat but only samples come not cluster numbers like below

```
> DimPlot(pbmc, reduction = "umap",group.by = "samples")
>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any help that to get something like the first figure? Having cluster numbers and coloured by sample names please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that makes use of `LabelClusters()` from `Seurat`:

```
# creating a plot and assigning it to the "plot" variable
# coloring by sample id and turning labels off
plot <- 
DimPlot(
  pbmc,
  reduction = "umap",
  group.by = "some_random_sample_id",
  label = FALSE,
)

# here is the trick, adding cluster labels to the "data" variable of the "plot"
# without this, the "plot" object would not have the clustering information but only embeddings and sample id
plot$data$seurat_clusters<- pbmc@meta.data$seurat_clusters

# and here is a sanity check to see if cluster labels are transferred to the "right places"
all(rownames(plot$data) == rownames(pbmc@meta.data))

LabelClusters(plot, id = "seurat_clusters")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I get this error  > LabelClusters(plot, id = "seurat_clusters")
Error in LabelClusters(plot, id = "seurat_clusters") : 
  Cannot find variable seurat_clusters in plotting data
>

Comment: The problem is kind of obvious, did you check wheter `plot$data` contains a column called `seurat_clusters`?